# Simple solution for converting JSON to HTML?

Tags: json

Is there an at least relatively simple solution for converting JSON to HTML (i.e. without having to download any engines or libraries, or use a JSON-to-XML conversion tool; just a built-in way to do it like with XML and XSLT)? Or might I just as well stick with using XML and XSLT if I want to do it the simple way?

Example: Say I wanted to convert list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <item letter="A">3</item>
    <item letter="B">5</item>
    <item letter="C">2</item>
</list>
```

...into XHTML format (e.g. this):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>A - 3</li>
            <li>B - 5</li>
            <li>C - 2</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

...I would just need to create list.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.0" />

    <xsl:template match="/list">
        <html>
            <body>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="item" />
                </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
       <li><xsl:value-of select="@letter" /> - <xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...and add this to list.xml just under the XML declaration at the top:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="list.xsl"?>
```

I guess what I'm asking is, does JSON have a stylesheet format similar to what XSLT is for XML?

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail to get a useful response. You should probably include the format or an example of the input JSON, the expected output format or an example of the HTML you expect. Conversion between languages in always possible but rarely simple. That's why many programmers use Plugins and Libraries; to make it simple.

Comment: Edited the question to give an example.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no stylesheet for JSON. JSON is only data and is designed to be lightweight from the core: http://www.json.org/. You could think of it more like an array than structured data. For your application, you could use Javascript to parse the JSON and assign the values to existing HTML elements.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad, although to answer it simply there is no out-the-box XML-XSLT equivalent for JSON and XSLT itself has lost support over the years so I assume there won't be a generally accepted XSLT equivalent in the future. JSON isn't necessarily intended for this use case, instead to transport the notion of an object to fill a model to be passed to a view for display.

Comment: Ahh...so there is no "stylesheet" format to convert JSON to HTML, then?

Comment: Without using external libraries, no. I'm sure there's a few floating around although never looked into it. You could in theory go down the JSON->XML->XSLT->XHTML route but that seems overkill. Either roll your own HTML template engine which feeds in JSON, or stick with XML-XSLT.

Comment: +1 Thank you. It looks like, for simply formatting data to display on a web page, XML-XSLT is the best way to go.